# jQuery fancybox not working in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7, fancybox

I've got a problem in good old IE7, as one of my clients is still using it.

For some reason, fancybox doesn't open and just throws a JS error in the jquery file itself.

I've tried debugging it, but have not found the solution as of yet.

Can you guys help me out here?

The site is http://beta.baeckerei-glasenapp.de/filialen/ and, as you can see in other browsers, the fancybox should open once you click on one of the 9 elements.

BTW: The HTML is generated by my CMS, so please excuse the "dl>a", which is nit valid HTML5 AFAIK.

Thanks

Tobias Timpe

Comment: I think the version 2.0.5 was a little bit buggy. Why don't you upgrade to v2.0.6 and let see what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a new version, which may solve the issues you are struggling with:

http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/